# error in the usestate or in the uuid library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, project, use-state

I'm doing a project to manage patient appointments and everything was fine until I installed the 'uuid' library, the library didn't give me a problem, but from then on it gave me this error, apparently it is with the useState but not I find it, I thank you in advance!

error image...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkVAA.jpg)

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const Form = () => {

    //creando el State para las citas
    const [ cita, actualizarCita ] = useState({
        mascota: '',
        propietario: '',
        fecha: '',
        hora: '',
        sintomas: ''
    });

    const [ error, actualizarError ] = useState(false)

    // funcion que se ejecutara cada vez que el usuario escribe en el input para validar lo que hace
    const actualizarState = e => {
        actualizarCita({
            ...cita,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    // Extraer los valores de cita
    const { mascota, propietario, fecha, hora, sintomas } = cita;

    // Cuando el usuario envia el formulario
    const submitCita = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Validacion

        if(mascota.trim() === '' || propietario.trim() === '' || fecha.trim() === '' || hora.trim() === '' || sintomas.trim() === ''){
            actualizarError(true);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Eliminando el mensaje previo
    actualizarError(false);


    // Asignando un ID

    cita.id = uuidv4();

    return (
        <Fragment>

        <h2> Crear Cita </h2>

        { error ? <p className="alerta-error">Todos los campos son obligatorios</p> : null }

        <form
            onSubmit={submitCita}
        >
            <label>Nombre Mascota</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="mascota"
                className="u-full-width"
                placeholder="Nombre Mascota"
                onChange={actualizarState}
                value={mascota}
            />

            <label>Nombre Dueño </label>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="propietario"
                className="u-full-width"
                placeholder="Nombre dueño de la mascota"
                onChange={actualizarState}
                value={propietario}
            />

            <label>Fecha </label>
            <input
                type="date"
                name="fecha"
                className="u-full-width"
                onChange={actualizarState}
                value={fecha}
            />

            <label>Hora </label>
            <input
                type="time"
                name="hora"
                className="u-full-width"
                placeholder="Nombre dueño de la mascota"
                onChange={actualizarState}
                value={hora}
            />

            <label>Sintomas</label>
            <textarea
                className="u-full-width"
                name="sintomas"
                onChange={actualizarState}
                value={sintomas}
            ></textarea>

            <button
                type="submit"
                className="u-full-width button-primary"
            >Agregar Cita</button>


        </form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't update state out side function,

```
actualizarError(false);
```

you should remove this, otherwise infinite re-render

Comment: thanks that was, but how can delete the message previous??

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure what the problem might be without a proper sandbox ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) for example).

But the error seems to indicate that you've gotten stuck in an infinite loop, which usually means the component is cause its own state dependencies to change, which causes a redraw (which again causes a change, etc.)

I'd start by moving

```
    // Eliminando el mensaje previo
    actualizarError(false);
```

into

```
    const actualizarState = e => {
        actualizarCita({
            ...cita,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
```